# Pass string as arguments with spaces in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a CLI program that generates arguments as one string for another CLI program. I call both from BASH. Here is simplified version of what I have:

```sh
produce_args() {
    echo "arg1 \"ar g2\" arg3"
}

consume_args() {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}

TMP="$(produce_args)"
consume_args $TMP
```

It prints:

```
arg1
"ar
g2"
arg3
```

So, argument 2 was split to two arguments. How to see an output like this instead?

```
arg1
ar g2
arg3
```

I can change my generator CLI program and BASH script but not consumer program. Also I can use `zsh` but I don't really think that matters in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'eval' to on the call to consume_args. It will allow the shell to process in the quoted string from the produce args as a single argument:

```
#! /bin/bash

produce_args() {
    echo "arg1 \"ar g2\" arg3"
}

consume_args() {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}

TMP="$(produce_args)"
eval consume_args $TMP
```

Comment: Oh, gosh, man! That simple! It's a terrible answer :( Thank you a lot!

Comment: This is just asking for problems when `produce_args` changes. Consider, for example, if the output of `produce_args` produces an argument with more than one consecutive whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I'd abstain from using eval as much as possible, albeit I don't mind using it if necessary.  In your case I'd probably use a new-line as arg-separator, modify IFS accordingly, and make `TMP` an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
produce_args() {
        echo -e "arg1\nar g2\narg3"
}
consume_args() {
        for arg in "${@}"; do
                echo "$arg"
        done
}
NL="
"
OLDIFS="${IFS}"
IFS="${NL}"
declare -a TMP
TMP=($(produce_args))
IFS="${OLDIFS}"
consume_args "${TMP[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!